# WP8/C# - Fill Grid From Collection?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm creating a sound board type app purely for learning purposes. What I would like to do is define a collection of Sound objects - my Sound object contains Name, File Path and Image properties - , and fill a grid with these objects.

Is it possible to fill a Grid from a collection? I know it can be done with a List, but I'm using a grid to lay out my sounds in XAML in a grid format.

Comment: http://diggthedrazen.com/2011/07/07/binding-clr-objects-to-your-uiwindows-phone/

Comment: That's for a ListBox, I'm doing it on a Grid.

Comment: Sorry, ignore my last comment. Put it in an answer and I will vote, that link was perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post shows how to create View Models of your data, and bind them to a grid:

**DataBinding C# objects in Windows Phone**
http://diggthedrazen.com/2011/07/07/binding-clr-objects-to-your-uiwindows-phone/

> In this post we’ll see how to bind a collection of items to a ListBox
>   and generate simple templates for each ListBoxItem. We’ll also look at
>   C# and how to define collections and what types of collections should
>   you use when binding data.